# How can I parse/extract data from an un-normalized table cell in MySql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am working with a table in MySql that has multiple values stored in a table's cell. In the cell, the values are separated by a comma. How can I extract the data into a new table and also keep track of their order?

The table has the following columns:

COLUMNS:

- PersonId (Primary Key)
- AddressRecords (One or more foreign keys to an address table)

SAMPLE RECORDS:

PersonId; AddressRecords

1, [3,5,7]

2, [1,2]

3, [2,3]

4, [1]

I am looking for the following output in a new table:

RECORDS:

Id, PersonId, AddressId, SortOrder

1,1,3,1

2,1,5,2

3,1,7,3

4,2,1,1

5,2,2,2

6,3,2,1

7,3,3,2

8,4,1,1

Keeping the order of the values is very important.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I’m using MySQL 5.7

Comment: I recommend not generating/storing the row numbers.  Just Google for "MySQL csv to rows" for some solutions.